# Getting current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block error when trying to insert data to postgres table

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into a Postgres table. I have used the below code. Can anyone help me with why I am getting this error and how it could be solved? I did refer to a few solutions and nothing worked. I have used two functions here. One for data preparation and one for data loading. The df contains 700000 rows. I had written a df with 1000 rows using the same approach and it had worked, but when I am doing it for a larger df I am getting the error: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

```
db_engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(
        'predictive_maintenance_rw',
        '',
        'dev-da-aurora.cluster-xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        5432,
        'predictive_maintenance'
    )
)

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname = "predictive_maintenance", 
    user = "user_rw", 
    password = "xxxxxx",
    
    host = "dev-da-aurora.cluster-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 
    port = 5432
)


def data_prep_circularity(path,engine, conn,schema,table):
    
    for x in os.listdir(path):
        for y in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x):
            if "FP" in y :     
                for z in os.listdir(path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y):
                    final_data = []
                    if "Circularity" in z:
                        cols_cir = ["axis", "machinenumber", "time", "timeoffset", "reference_value_pos_axis_1","actual_value_pos_axis_1",
                                    "actual_value_pos_axis_2","reference_value_pos_axis_2","plane"]
                        rows_cir = []
                        for xml_files in os.listdir (path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y +"\\" + z):
                            fullname_cir = (path+"\\" + x + "\\" + y +"\\" + z+"\\"+xml_files)
                            xmlparse_cir = Xet.parse(fullname_cir)
                            # Parsing the XML file
                            root_cir = xmlparse_cir.getroot()
                            for i in root_cir:    
                                # finding axis 
                                if "XY" in fullname_cir:
                                    axis = 'XY'
                                else :   
                                    axis = 'XZ'
                                # Finding the machine number
                                machinenumber = x.split("_")[1]
                                time = fullname_cir.split("-",2)[2].split("\\",1)[0]
                                timeoffset = i.find("timeoffset").text
                                reference_value_pos_axis_1 = i.find("f3").text
                                actual_value_pos_axis_1 = i.find("f1").text
                                actual_value_pos_axis_2 = i.find("f2").text
                                reference_value_pos_axis_2 = i.find("f4").text
                                # finding plane 
                                if "10" in fullname_cir:
                                    plane = '10'
                                else :   
                                    plane = '150'
                                rows_cir.append({"axis": axis,
                                "machinenumber": machinenumber,
                                 "time": time ,
                                 "timeoffset": timeoffset,
                                 "reference_value_pos_axis_1" :reference_value_pos_axis_1,
                                 "actual_value_pos_axis_1": actual_value_pos_axis_1,
                                 "actual_value_pos_axis_2": actual_value_pos_axis_2,
                                 "reference_value_pos_axis_2" :reference_value_pos_axis_2,
                                "plane": plane })
  
                            df = pd.DataFrame(rows_cir, columns=cols_cir)
    
            # Writing dataframe to csv
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    table_name='dev_fingerprint_circularitytest'
    data_load(df, engine, conn, schema, table_name)


def data_load(chunk, engine, conn, schema, table_name):
    sio = StringIO()
    sio.write(chunk.replace(['\r','\n','\t'], ' ', regex=True).to_csv(index=None, header=None, sep='\t', na_rep = 'NULL'))  # Write the Pandas DataFrame as a csv to the buffer
    #sio.write(chunk.to_csv(index=None, header=None, sep='\t', na_rep = 'NULL'))  # Write the Pandas DataFrame as a csv to the buffer
    sio.seek(0)  # Be sure to reset the position to the start of the stream

    with conn.cursor() as c:
        c.copy_from(sio, schema +"." + table_name, columns=chunk.columns, sep='\t', null='NULL')
        conn.commit() 

data_prep_circularity(path,db_engine, conn, 'public','dev_fingerprint_circularitytest')
```

Comment: That is a follow-up error, since a previous statement in the transaction has failed. Find and fix that first error.

Comment: @ Laurenz Albe, I had stored the data frame in a csv file and checked it, it was working as expected.

Comment: That may be so, but you still have to look for the first error you get if you want to solve your problem. Be open to the possibility that you did something wrong somewhere.